# When reviewing the triage queue, should I hit Requires Editing when the user say thanks?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, thanks

Let's assume we have a question posted. And let's assume this question is brilliant from a new user. Let's also assume that this new user added the text "Thanks" or "Any help would be appreciated" at the end of the post.

If I tackle such a question in the triage queue, should I hit "Looks OK" or "Requires Editing"? Of course, if I could I would simply delete that gratitude, but my rating does not allow that, so which one should I choose?

Comment: Assuming the question really is brilliant and is 100% definitely on-topic on the site with no doubt about it, then Requires Editing is the correct choice. _Alternatively_, skip the review, leave it to the army of "Looks OK"/"Requires Editing" reviewers behind you, and look for bad ones which might slip through the net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure that the question is an awesome question (not off-topic, not a duplicate and no other close reason applies to it) then you should vote "Requires Editing".

We do not allow noise, signatures or thanks in posts. They need to be removed. If the only thing that the question requires in your opinion is the removal of such phrases then it means you should send it to Help and Improvement queue where someone can remove the clutter.

Don't press "Requires Editing" if the question needs to be closed or needs more clarity from the person who asked it. **If you are not sure whether the question should be closed or not, just SKIP!**